# How to solve mysql errno:-1?

Tags: mysql

I used "alter table" command to add a foreign key in a table, after that I refresh my database then I saw there is not my table in my database,and I can not re-create this table at all,errorno is -1
I do not have access to the files table On the server to delete them also I do not want to create other table with other storage engine or create another database,In fact my records in this table are very important.

Comment: So the question is a) What is error -1 b) How do I create a table or c) How do I restore a missing table and its data?

Comment: Can you re-add the image and/or add the statement and the complete error message as text?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this errno: -1 happened when there was a missing `<table>.frm` file in `/var/lib/mysql/<database>/` directory. I fixed it by deleting the corresponding `<table>.ibd` file and restoring the table from a backup.